# Mock window.location.reload with sinon

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, sinon, window.location

I'm writting tests with sinon for a section of Vue code that performs a reload with `window.location.reload();`.

The code works correctly, but the test is failing with an error `Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)`

If I delete that line of code, the tests don't crash.

How can I write a sinon test that runs correctly through that line of code?
I'm not sure if I need to stub that line, although I'm not sure how could I do it for a property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Consider `onbeforeunload` which throws an error and prevents an actual page reloading, and `assert.throws` catching the error. Something like this:

```js
describe("#location.reload", () => {
  it("works well", () => {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
      throw new Error();
    };
    assert.throws(location.reload);
  });
});
```